# How is Scala faster than Java when both are compiled into `.class` file which is run by JVM only?

Tags: java, scala, performance, jvm, microbenchmark

I have read at many places that Scala is 20% faster than Java. However, I couldn't find an explanation to this. I have quite a good experience with Java but never really worked on Scala and was doing some research on the language choice for my next project.
My idea was that once the program is compiled, the JVM doesn't care if it was written in Scala or Java. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Edit: Is there any research that proves Scala compiler has better compile optimizations as compared to Java compiler?

P.S.: I am not talking about Compile time, I am talking about run-time only.

Comment: Why do you think the output file format of a compiler controls the speed the program can run?

Comment: Think about this: write a program in C. Compile it with the latest version of Clang with all optimizations turned off. Compile it again with the latest version of Clang with all optimizations turned on. Which one of the two would you expect to be faster? According to your logic, they should both be equally fast because once they are compiled, the CPU doesn't care if it was written in C or in C. Do you think that is true?

Comment: Thanks for this example. I was considering the compiled files after the optimizations turned on. So, does this mean for the same algorithm written in Scala and Java, the optimizations are made better in Scala compiler as compared to Java compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably seeing discussion of [this paper](https://days2011.scala-lang.org/sites/days2011/files/ws3-1-Hundt.pdf). This is the key sentence:

> Scala concise notation and powerful language features allowed for the best optimization of code complexity

The key point is that the Scala performance was better because it was quicker to write a more optimised version of the algorithm, rather than because the compiler did a better job of optimisation.

Comment: This. You can't optimize your code if the language forces you to write so much ceremony that it obscures what the code is actually doing. Languages that allow you to write modular, well-factored, high-level code with powerful abstractions make it easy to radically change your algorithmic approach or architecture, which is usually what gives you the biggest performance increase.

Comment: Your point is absolutely correct but my question was more towards the run-time of programs. Even though the language provides powerful abstraction and modularity, at the end they compile to lower level byte-code. Hence, while the application is running, the expected run-time performance should ideally be same for both the language (except if Scala provides better compile optimizations).

Comment: My question was also if it is true that Scala provides better compile optimizations. I read blogs about it but couldn't find a proved research paper stating this.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Imho it's more complicated than that, as JVM is also not just well suited for functional programming with lack of value types and references everywhere, and idiomatic scala code often can generate a lot of garbage + will generate bytecode that JIT is not familiar with and might have hard time finding patterns in it, after all it was written with java in mind. And when trying to make micro optimizations then often its best to write in java to not fall into any abstraction traps. (same goes for languages like kotlin)

Comment: @GotoFinal: I saw a video of a talk by Cliff Click from Azul more than ten years ago, where he demonstrated running Rich Hickey's Ant Colony Simulation Clojure Example on one of Azul's JCA Java Compute Accelerators with 864 CPU cores. The simulation used 700 cores at full capacity, generating over 20 GiByte/s of garbage in a ~150 GiByte heap. The garbage collector never broke a sweat. According to Cliff Click, at no point during the whole exercise did the combined usage of JIT and GC go over ~40 cores, i.e. there were always well over 100 cores still left for user code.

Comment: And that was over 10 years ago. If a GC had no problem dealing with 20 GiByte/s of garbage over 10 years ago, with all the advances in GC technology we have seen since then, I would assume that would be even less of a problem now. And while this was not demonstrated in this example, the JCA also had no problem with multi-terabyte heaps, again, we are talking over 10 years ago.

Comment: @JörgWMittag it does have issues with much smaller allocation rates already, but these issues are just usually small enough to live with. But you can see affecting them performance, as after all it still causes pauses. Especially visible while doing anything with rendering where each pause is often visible to user, like gamedev.